# XML is not parsed in php

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller, I read a data from DB. (where `AlarmDeatils` is a stored as XML content. **Eg:AlarmDeatils** column contains

```
<SiteAlarmDetails>
    <AlertId>89637</AlertId>
    <SiteCode>20157498</SiteCode>
    <SiteName>newport</SiteName>
    <TankNumber>4</TankNumber>
    <DispenserNumbedr>3</DispenserNumbedr>
    <HoseNumber>3</HoseNumber>
    <GradeId>11</GradeId>
    <GradeName>PULP98</GradeName>
    <AlarmUTCDateTime>2015-10-08T12:00:00</AlarmUTCDateTime>
    <AlarmClearedUTCDateTime>2015-10-08T22:00:00</AlarmClearedUTCDateTime>
    <UTCTimeZoneName>GMT Standard Time</UTCTimeZoneName>
    <AlarmVolume>0</AlarmVolume>
    <AlarmLevel>0</AlarmLevel>
    <TankCapacity>0</TankCapacity>
    <TankCapacityPercent>0</TankCapacityPercent>
    <TankOverfill>0</TankOverfill>
    <TankUllage>0</TankUllage>
    <ProductLoss>0</ProductLoss>
    <HoursElapsed>10</HoursElapsed>
    <WaterLevel>0</WaterLevel>
    <AvgSalesPerDay>0</AvgSalesPerDay>
    <DaysToStockOut>0</DaysToStockOut>
    <InvalidDataCount>0</InvalidDataCount>
    <ValidDataCount>0</ValidDataCount>
    <ZeroVolumeCount>0</ZeroVolumeCount>
    <ZeroProductLevelCount>0</ZeroProductLevelCount>
    <ZeroTotaliserAmountCount>0</ZeroTotaliserAmountCount>
</SiteAlarmDetails>
```

I read that that row in my controller like;

```
  $tableAlarm = \DB::table('Alarm')
                ->where('Alarm.AlarmId', '=', $id)->first();
```

and when I use

```
 var_dump($tableAlarm);
```

I get

```
object(stdClass)#241 (10) { ["AlarmId"]=> string(6) "245039" ["MessageNotificationId"]=> string(6) "219078" ["CompanyId"]=> string(2) "19" ["CompanyCode"]=> string(7) "MCCOLLS" ["AlertTypeId"]=> string(2) "23" ["AlarmDetails"]=> string(1408) "979381320106510Eyemouth Service Station2017-07-23T21:26:499999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999GMT Standard Time00000005000000000001-01-01T00:00:000001-01-01T00:00:000001-01-01T00:00:000000001-01-01T00:00:00" ["AlertProcessStateId"]=> string(1) "2" ["UTCDateTimeInserted"]=> string(27) "2017-07-24 02:15:36.9300000" ["UTCDateTimeUpdated"]=> string(27) "2017-07-24 02:15:36.9300000" ["RowDataVersion"]=> string(16) "00000000117D854B" }
```

Im trying to parse the **AlarmDeatils** column like;

```
$alertXml = simplexml_load_string( $tableAlarm->AlarmDetails);
 echo $alertXml;//Nothing printed
```

But i'm not getting anything :( I'm trying to process that xml like;

```
foreach($alertXml->children() as $alerts)
{
   print_r( $alerts->AlertId);// **getting SimpleXMLElement Object ()**
   echo  $alerts->AlertId;//**Nothing printed**
}
```

Comment: `simplexml_load_string` returns `an object` which you can't echo. Try `print_r`. [simplexml_load_string](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Comment: in this `simplexml_load_string` you have to load a string instead of an `object`

Comment: Can you share you `XML` and expected output?

Comment: I dont see any elements in your AlarmDetails. You sure it's XML?

Comment: use `$tableAlarm['AlarmDetails']` instead of `$tableAlarm->AlarmDetails`

Comment: @SahilGulati thank you it works.so the way I read AlertId in my foreach loop is fine?

Comment: @SahilGulati I have provided sample xml in my question

Comment: @SahilGulati I getSimpleXMLElement Object ( ) when trying AlertId from the   $alertXml  inside foreach loop. I have updated question

Comment: @Ratha can you share complete `XML` content and expected output so that it can be helpful for other future readers also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful. Try this simplest one.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/850085)

```
<?php

$xmlString=<<<XML
<SiteAlarmDetails>
  <AlertId>89637</AlertId>
  <SiteCode>20157498</SiteCode>
  <SiteName>newport</SiteName>
  <TankNumber>4</TankNumber>
  <DispenserNumbedr>3</DispenserNumbedr>
  <HoseNumber>3</HoseNumber>
  <GradeId>11</GradeId>
  <GradeName>PULP98</GradeName>
  <AlarmUTCDateTime>2015-10-08T12:00:00</AlarmUTCDateTime>
  <AlarmClearedUTCDateTime>2015-10-08T22:00:00</AlarmClearedUTCDateTime>
  <UTCTimeZoneName>GMT Standard Time</UTCTimeZoneName>
  <AlarmVolume>0</AlarmVolume>
  <AlarmLevel>0</AlarmLevel>
  <TankCapacity>0</TankCapacity>
  <TankCapacityPercent>0</TankCapacityPercent>
  <TankOverfill>0</TankOverfill>
  <TankUllage>0</TankUllage>
  <ProductLoss>0</ProductLoss>
  <HoursElapsed>10</HoursElapsed>
  <WaterLevel>0</WaterLevel>
  <AvgSalesPerDay>0</AvgSalesPerDay>
  <DaysToStockOut>0</DaysToStockOut>
  <InvalidDataCount>0</InvalidDataCount>
  <ValidDataCount>0</ValidDataCount>
  <ZeroVolumeCount>0</ZeroVolumeCount>
  <ZeroProductLevelCount>0</ZeroProductLevelCount>
  <ZeroTotaliserAmountCount>0</ZeroTotaliserAmountCount>
</SiteAlarmDetails>
XML;

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
echo (string)$xml->AlertId;//type-casted to string
echo PHP_EOL;
echo (string)$xml->SiteCode;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo (string)$xml->SiteName;
```